# Размытие Blur на фон блока

Tags: html, css

Есть секция, которая содержит вложенные блоки, картинки и тд. На этой секции фоном задана картинка, но мне её нужно размыть так, чтобы другие элементы оставались не тронутыми.

```
<section class="test"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius et ea nemo deleniti natus aliquid</p> </section>
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как это сделать? Нужно чтобы был размыт только фон.

Answer (score 9):

**Вариант 1**

```css
.test{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.test:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals') no-repeat center top;  
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);   
  filter: blur(5px);  
}
.test p{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="test">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius et ea nemo deleniti natus aliquid</p> 
</section>
```

**Вариант 2**

```css
.test{
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
}
.img-bg-test{
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);   
  filter: blur(5px);
}
.test p{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="test">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius et ea nemo deleniti natus aliquid</p> 
<img  src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals" class="img-bg-test" />
</section>
```

Comment: Нет картинки в img

Answer (score 1):

```css
.test {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100px;
}
.img-bg-test {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);   
  filter: blur(5px);
}
p {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 20px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="test">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius et ea nemo deleniti natus aliquid</p>
  <img  src="https://skrinshoter.ru/p/300121/v6280N.png?download=1&name=%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%2030-01-2021%2016:53:26.png" class="img-bg-test">
</section>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]