# Как применить filter blur на фон

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Можно ли сделать filter: blur(), только для фона? Чтобы он не касался блоков[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `filter:blur()` для фона? Как я понимаю вы хотите сделать как на картинке? `blur()` предназначенная для другого, в основном именно картинок, вы можете использовать `background: rgba(255,255,255,.5)`. Если я правильно понял

Comment: Либо же, воспользоваться: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538979/423786

Answer (score 0):

можете использовать [backdrop-filer](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter)

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]